# When can obj !== obj be true?

Tags: javascript

I want to know when `obj !== obj` can be true?

This is what I saw a line of code in the book, I was very puzzled.

```
var result = class2type[(obj == null || obj !== obj)] ? obj : toString.call(obj) ] || obj.nodeName || "#";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The one case that pops to my mind is [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN):

```
console.log(NaN !== NaN) // true
```